# Jquery scrolling, how to add offset?

Tags: jquery, scroll

There is my js code. This is page scrolling script. Things I need to do is to make **offset (78px)** and set `active` class to element (Home - first menu item) on start (until I use this script).
You can check this on [this website](http://lebsajt.pl/specify).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var full_url = this.href;

        var parts = full_url.split('#');
        var trgt = parts[1];

        var target_offset = $('#'+trgt).offset();
        var target_top = target_offset.top;

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 500);


    });

    $('nav .menu li a').click(function(){
         $('nav .menu li a').removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active');
    });

});
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: ok i figured out this first problem with offset, just added '$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top -100 }, 500);'
Still need help with active first menu element when website starts.

Comment: Post your HTML for the element you want to modify.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mGUMd/
I need to make active home button.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `id` attribute to the `a` elements.

**HTML**

```
<li><a href="#section-splash" alt="" title="" id="home">home</a></li>
```

Then use jQuery to add class.

**jQuery**

```
$("#home").addClass('active');
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BygBR/)